# how to show exception variable value in alert box in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, try-catch

I have the following code, but the alert box is not displaying.

```
try
{
    do something..          
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ex+"')</script>");
}
```

If I use this code, the alert box appears.

```
try
{
    do some thing
}
catch (Exception ex)
{           
    Response.Write("<script>alert(\"an error occur\")</script>");
}
```

How can I display the exception variable in an alert box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to show the stacktrace:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
```

or if you want only the message

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");
```

Comment: Used this in a classic asp to do something similar and it worked for me as well.  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ex.Message+"')</script>");
```

Have a look at the class [Exception Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx)

Comment: The message should be HtmlEncoded. it could contain " or other charaters that will make the html rendering behave different from the intent

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim message = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rs)
 Dim script = String.Format("alert({0});", message)
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "", Script, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whthr you r using update panel in that page.It may sometimes work if the update panel is there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful and properly escape the Javascript string you are generating ... Imagine there are single quotes in the Exception's message ...

Single-quotes (`'`) need to be escaped (`\'`)

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message).Replace("'","\\'" ) + "')</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
  string jscriptCustInfo = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>";
  jscriptCustInfo = jscriptCustInfo + "alert('Dividend Posting Done, Batch No: "+lblBatch.Text+"');";

  jscriptCustInfo = jscriptCustInfo + "</script>";
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", jscriptCustInfo, false);
```